Expo React native Keep app running in the **background**
I Have this code that fetchData every 10 seconds
  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setSecondsElapsed((prevSecondsElapsed) => prevSecondsElapsed + 1);
      if (secondsElapsed % 10 === 0) {
        // Every 10 seconds
        fetchData();
      }
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [secondsElapsed]);

and the fetch method :
const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await FetchData();
      setValue(data);

      const newLength = data.length;
      let hasNewItems = false;

      if (data && newLength > prevLengthRef.current) {
        console.log("New Order Received:", newLength - prevLengthRef.current,"new items added" );
        hasNewItems = true;
        sendNotification(expoPushToken); // Send notification

        setInitialLength(newLength);
        prevLengthRef.current = newLength;
      } else {
        console.log("No new orders received.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error.message);
      Alert.alert("Error", "Failed to fetch data. Please try again later.");
    }
  };

with this solution it is not  working in the Background how to set the app working on the background even the app is closed

To fetch in the background Expo has a cross platform api for it
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/background-fetch/
